# How to add project phonegap/cordova in existing project android studio?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-plugins

This is my directory folder in my android project.

[image]

This is directory folder phonegap/cordova as image below.

[image]

I try to combine project phonegap/cordova into my android project, but a got a lot of message error in gradle.build. I start confuse when folder structure in phonegap/cordova different with my current project android.

Comment: Why would you want to mix both.. ??

Comment: @GokulNathKP I found phonegap/cordova project sample in internet with webRTC. I try to combine that project in my current project, because in current project I need feature webRTC such as project phonegap/cordova webRTC. It's possible or not to combine?